# Align a large image to its centre

Tags: alignment

I have to insert a large image in my thesis report. For some reason the image is getting right aligned in the page by default. I tried to center the image using \hspace{-1.4cm}, but no improvement. Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
%\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, BCOR1cm]{scrbook}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

%function definition for starting intro from first section.
\def\frontmatter{%
  %\pagenumbering{roman}
  \setcounter{page}{1}
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
}%

\def\mainmatter{%
  %\pagenumbering{arabic}
  %\setcounter{page}{1}
  \setcounter{section}{0}
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
}%

\def\backmatter{%
  %\pagenumbering{arabic}
  
}%
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}%%%
\usepackage{wrapfig}%%%
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{commath}\usepackage{amsmath}
\linespread{1.32}
%\usepackage[top = 2.8cm, bottom = 3.5cm, inner = 3cm, outer = 3cm, headheight = 15pt]{geometry}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={5.7in, 8.72in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\leftmark}
\cfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}


\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{titletoc}
%\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
%\usepackage{picins}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\newenvironment{bottompar}{\par\vspace*{\fill}}{\clearpage}



\begin{document} 

%%%%%%Lots of text 
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\hspace{-1.4cm}
\includegraphics[height=5.4in,width=7.4in]{images/image1.png}
\caption[demo]{demo}
\vspace{0cm}
\label{fig:arc6}
\end{figure}
%%%%%%Text

\backmatter
\thispagestyle{plain}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{References}

%\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\end{document}
```

The position of the image looks something like this:
[image]

Comment: (1) Please make sure your code is even remotely compilable (there is no `\begin/end{document}` and `[H]` (which generally should not be used is not suppoted without additional package. (2) Are you sure the image is correctly cropped (i.e. doesn't have excessive white space in it). (3) can we see the image? (4) When even you feel the need to use `\hspace` or `\vspace` in a document like that, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: 1. Sorry for not posting all the packages, it was quite long. 2.  The image was cropped correctly. 3. unfortunately, the image cannot be shared. Basically the image is in .png format and is not getting aligned in center like rest of my images.

Answer (score 1):

Your image is wider than the `textwidth` and can not be centered. Reduce the designated width of your graphic to not more than the `textwidth`.

```
% picprob.tex  SE

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,BCOR1cm]{scrbook}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{mwe}  % provides example images
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum} % provides many lines of text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[H]  %% your code
\centering
\hspace{-1.4cm}
\includegraphics[height=5.4in,width=7.4in]{images/image1.png}
\caption[demo]{demo}
\vspace{0cm}
\label{fig:arc6}
\end{figure}

Text

%%% my code
\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}%[H]  %% my code
\centering
%\hspace{-1.4cm}
%\includegraphics[height=5.4in,width=7.4in]{example-image}
\includegraphics[height=5.4in,width=5.4in]{example-image}
\caption[demo]{demo}
\vspace{0cm}
\label{fig:arc6}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Please don't use the `[H]` float option as it nullifies the float; if you insist on not having a float then do not call for one, there are other means of adding a caption to a graphic or table.